# What does ProducerPerformance Tool in Kafka give?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

What does running following Kafka tool actually give ?

./bin/kafka-run-class.sh org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance --throughput=10000--topic=TOPIC--num-records=50000000 --record-size=200 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=SERVERS buffer.memory=67108864 batch.size=64000

When running with a single producer I get 90MB/s. When I use 3 separate producers on separate nodes I get only around 60 MB/s per producer. ( My Kafka cluster consists of 2 nodes, and topic has 6 partitions )

1. What does 90 MB/s mean? Is it the maximum rate at which a producer can produce?
2. Does partition count affect this value?
3. Why it drops to 60 MB/s when there are 3 producers ( still no network saturation on broker front)?

Thank you